# If I delete an array of pointers to nodes, will the nodes themselves be deleted?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, nodes, delete-operator

Let's say I create an array of pointers to nodes, each containing a car object member variable, in order to print them out in descending order of mpg. Once I'm finished sorting the array in descending order of MPG and printing out the final results, I would like to delete the array of pointers I created.

Would deleting the array at the end also delete the nodes in the singly linked list?

```
cout << "\nCARS RANKED BY MPG\n-------------\n";

int capacity = count;                   //number of nodes in the list
Node **a = new Node*[capacity];            
int numOfElem = 0;

Node *currentCar = first;               //create a pointer to the first node in the list

while (numOfElem < count)
{
    a[numOfElem++] = currentCar;            //populate the array of pointers
    currentCar = currentCar->getLink();
}

//Do something....

delete[] a;                               //delete array of pointers
a = nullptr;
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you're only freeing the memory that `a` itself points to. The contents of that memory is not processed in any way.

If you want automatic "deletion" of objects, use either smart pointers, or better yet a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of *objects* (not pointers to objects).